# Looking for Jewish music that lifts the spirit

Tags: product-recommendation, music, performance-entertainment

I really love the soft sweet tones, chords and voices in the music of Shlomo Katz, Ishay Ribo, Yonathan Razel; but, searching for similar music, I just don't know where to go. Are there alternatives for this site, where I could ask questions about Jewish music?

If this isn't the right place, I will delete this post; it's just that I don't know where to ask this kind of question.

Please help me out..

Comment: how's something like this? http://torahreading.dafyomireview.com/cd/tehilim-sfardi2/001-020/tehilim-001.mp3

Comment: @רבותמחשבות thanks. Would love to see more suggestions along these lines. For after Tisha bAv ;->

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options

- Aaron Razel (Yonatan's brother)
- Ari Goldwag
- Ben Snof
- Eitan Katz
- Guy Tzvi Mintz
- Uri Davidi
- Yitzhak Meir
- Yosef Karduner

If I had to pick 3 I would pick (in order) Yitzhak Meir, Aaron Razel, Yosef Karduner.