# Listening to non-Jewish music

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, music

Is there anything wrong with listening to:

A) non-Jewish music that has no sexual content in it?

B) non-Jewish music that has no lyrics?

Comment: This question is not answerable without a working definition of “non-Jewish” music.

Comment: I've asked a very similiar question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97266/music-with-unholy-content-and-the-jewish-soul